# Get the ID and date which are not in the existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables which contain `ID, Date, var1, var2` ... and so on.

I use the below query to pull the `ID` from `Table2` to `Table1` where `ID` is not in `Table1`.

```sql
INSERT INTO [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.patient_reg
SELECT *
FROM   [192.168.36.36].mvdsc1302.dbo.patient_reg a
WHERE  a.patient_id NOT IN (SELECT patient_id
                            FROM   [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.patient_reg
                            WHERE  patient_id = a.patient_id)
```

The above code fetches new `IDs` to `Table1`. 
I need one more condition, What if I need to pull the `ID` which already exists in `table1`, but the newly entered `date` for the `ID` `(duplicate ID with different date)`?

Comment: Are these tables even different?  The names differ only be case.

Comment: No, Actually the table name are same but that's all from different servers. To get a clear view just you consider it as Table1 and Table2

Comment: I don't think this can be done in single query as the first condition required `Insert` which you already had done & other condition required an `Update`.  You can use `Replace` only if both tables have same schema & you're fine with copying the whole row from table2 to table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you wanted?

```
REPLACE INTO [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg
SELECT *
FROM [192.168.36.36].MVDSC1302.DBO.Patient_Reg a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT *
     FROM [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg b
     WHERE b.patient_id=a.patient_id
       AND b.Date=a.Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Except patient_id

```
INSERT INTO [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg
SELECT * FROM [192.168.36.36].MVDSC1302.DBO.Patient_Reg a
Where a.patient_id  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT patient_id  FROM [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg)
```

Except patient_id and Date

```
     INSERT INTO [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg
            SELECT * FROM [192.168.36.36].MVDSC1302.DBO.Patient_Reg a
            Where a.patient_id  NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT patient_id  FROM [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg)
   AND a.DATE NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg
SELECT *
FROM [192.168.36.36].MVDSC1302.DBO.Patient_Reg a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM [192.168.0.241].mvdsc1302.dbo.Patient_Reg b
WHERE b.patient_id=a.patient_id AND b.Date=a.Date)
```